# Javascript Slideshow Glitches When Clicking Empty Space Around Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, slideshow

So I got this slideshow code working, where when you click an image, it fades into another image. However, if, for example, there was a vertical orientated image with empty space on its right, if you click that space the whole slideshow kind of glitches out.

Here's my website where you can test it out:

http://danielshultz.github.io

**The code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fn.nextOrFirst = function (selector) {
    var next = this.next(selector);
    return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
};
$("#cf2 img").click(function() {
    $(this)
    .removeClass('visible')
    .nextOrFirst()
    .addClass('visible');
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#cf2 {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#cf2 img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf2 img.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cf2" class="shadow">
  <img class="visible" src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" alt="1"/>
  <img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-45891755,width-640,resizemode-4/nasas-images-of-most-remarkable-events-you-cant-miss.jpg" alt="2"/>
  <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/03/article-2486855-192ACC5200000578-958_964x682.jpg" alt="3"/>
  <img src="http://mstatic.mit.edu/nom150/items/199-HybridImage.jpg" alt="4"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried to find the glitch, I can't find anything. Can you be more specific as to how it this glitch acts? The page freezes up? The selection highlighting sticks? A swarm of locusts invade your home? (That's happens  to me on occasions).

Comment: I got it figured out. But thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

*If i understood, the problem here is when you click outside the image but inside the square of the previous image, then the slide does not change*.

This approach, makes no changes in yout javascript but changes the html and some selectors.

In the example below, I wrapped each `<img>` into a `'<div>'` and changed the selectors to match with those divisions. Minor stylings too.

So, if you click outside the image but over the div, the slide changes as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.nextOrFirst = function (selector) {
        var next = this.next(selector);
        return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
    };
    $("#cf2 div.holder").click(function() {
        $(this)
        .removeClass('visible')
        .nextOrFirst()
        .addClass('visible');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 8pt;
 color: #000;
}

#cf2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#cf2 div.holder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf2 div.holder img {
    max-height: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
}

#cf2 div.holder.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}


.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<td valign="center">
<div id="cf2" class="shadow">
<div class="holder visible">
<img src="//danielshultz.github.io/Images/Cute-Door-1.jpg" alt="1"/></div>
<div class="holder"><img src="//danielshultz.github.io/Images/Cute-Door-2.jpg" alt="2"/></div>
<div class="holder"><img src="//danielshultz.github.io/Images/Cute-Door-3.jpg" alt="3"/></div>
</div>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah! This makes so much sense. Thank you so much, worked perfectly. :) Still new to Java, clearly!